# How can I store a float with @AppStorage with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift

I have a float (`rate`) that can be set by the user for this app. I would like to keep this variable persistent, so I would like to use the `@AppStorage` property wrapper. The problem I'm having is that `@AppStorage("rate) var rate: Float = 0.5` gives `No exact matches in call to initializer`. After some brief googling, I learned that you cannot store floats with app storage. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Use a `Double` instead of a `Float`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the definition of `AppStorage` you can find the following allowed types:

- `Bool`
- `Int`
- `Double`
- `String`
- `URL`
- `Data`
- enum with `Int` raw value
- enum with `String` raw value
- `Bool?`
- `Int?`
- `Double?`
- `String?`
- `URL?`
- `Data?`
- optional enum with `Int` raw value
- optional enum with `String` raw value

So you should probably use `Double`, rather than `Float` (you shouldn't really use `Float` anyway, since it's 32-bit rather than 64-bit).